# How to get SVN revision number automatically into my Matlab code

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, matlab

Is there a method to get the svn revision number, of a specific file (.m), directly from code (Matlab)?

I need something like a Matlab function getSVNRevisionNumber(file.m)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVN supports keywords, thus you need something like:

```
x='$Rev$'
```

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html

Comment: thanks for the answer...ok...but where can i do this? This is not a Matlab Syntax! Have I to add that line in a comment line?

Comment: This is valid matlab syntax, simply put it in a file, check it in and out. The svn server will replace it with something like `x="$Rev 1.20$"`

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but...when I write x="$Rev$", my Matlab tells me "Invalid character(s)". However if I commit and update my file there's no substitution in file.

Comment: check: http://www.aliaspooryorik.com/blog/index.cfm/e/posts.details/post/keyword-substitution-with-tortoisesvn-176. I don't really see how this helps  getting a file's revision number from another function though...

Comment: @Bobo87: Invalid caracter is fixed, i used the wrong quotation marks, confused by to many different programming languages...

Answer (score 5):

There's no builtin command to do that.
The easiest way to get that information probably is issuing a `system` command and parsing its output:

```
function rev = getRev(mfile)

    SVN_EXE= 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe';
    command = sprintf('"%s" info "%s"', SVN_EXE, mfile);
    [status,out] = system(command);

    % check everything went well:
    assert( ~status );

    % parse revision from output:
    rev = regexp(out, 'Revision: (\d+)', 'tokens', 'once');
    % alternatively - depending on which info you really want
    % rev = regexp(out, 'Last Changed Rev: (\d+)', 'tokens', 'once');

    rev = str2double(rev{1});
end
```

This doesn't handle unversioned files yet, and there might be a safer, more complete function doing that out there, but this is a start...

Unfortunately this is rather slow as well - on the other hand its only a few lines of code.
If you're not afraid of java and willing to use third-party software you could also easily use `svnkit` from within MATLAB.