# matlab executable returns SVN revision number

Tags: matlab, svn, build

We need to have an auditible way of telling which SVN revision number a given MATLAB executable was compiled with.

This should be part of the build process. A possible route would be that MATALB triggers a mcc build hook, calls SubWCRev.exe (returning revision number of SVn repo) and sets a variable name which is then returned when a parameter "--version" is passed to a function.

Has anyone any exprience of implementing something similar?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if in the build script, you created/updated a text file containing the revision number, which is being read out by the function when you pass the "version" parameter?

Comment: You could also do this based on subversion keywords:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html

Comment: thanks sebastian, i wasn't aware of SVN Keywords before (i'm a Git guy), this looks kind of useful although i would prefer the global SVN version, rather than the $LastChangedRevision...hey ho.

Answer (score 0):

The executable version works as well, I'm using that (since it was before someone pointed me to the keywords) as well in an automated deployment-script.
See this question for an answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19765856/2319400